# "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal Invocation" in a javascript method

Tags: javascript, spring, web, typeerror

I have this input I want to use in another controller:

```
<li><input type="text" placeholder="Buscar" id="idnavBusqueda" name="navBusqueda"></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="guardar()">Buscar</a></li>
```

And For that I use the method guardar():

```
function guardar() {
                console.log("HOLAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
                var userAmigo= document.getElementById("idnavBusqueda");
                $('#idnavBusqueda').load("/perfilBusqueda",{navBusqueda:     userAmigo});
            }
```

But everytime I hit the "Buscar" button, Chrome sends the error and it just redirects to the href on "buscar". Also I'm using Spring, if that's relevant. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter in [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) allows you to send additional data out to the server when you make the request. In your case, you're trying to send an element, `userAmigo`, as a POST value which won't work.

Instead, you probably want the value *associated* with `userAmigo`.

```
$('#idnavBusqueda').load('/perfilBusqueda', {
  navBusqueda: userAmigo.value
});
```

Comment: This worked, Ill validate yours because you were faster, but both answers are correct. Although I'm getting Error 500 now, I guess that's for another question.

Answer (score 1):

You're telling jQuery to serialize an HTMLElement. You probably wanted its *value*:

```
var userAmigo= document.getElementById("idnavBusqueda").value;
// ----------------------------------------------------^^^^^^
```